# Gratis data scraping tool to replace Import.io

Tags: gratis, data, scraping

I need to be able to scrape data from multiple websites regularly. Some coding is OK, but due to heavily constrained time the fewer things I have to learn like XPath, the better.

I used to use [Import.io](http://www.import.io) for this. They did a great job, but I think they encountered difficulty; either technical, financial, or both. Over the past 1 - 2 years their support forum went offline, their web app functionality has been reduced, and their desktop app quit working (at least on Windows).

I've found a couple of very expensive similar tools, but since this is just for a side-business that isn't earning income yet, I need something that's free, freemium, or very cheap.

Comment: Maybe http://scrapinghub.com/portia/ or https://www.parsehub.com (they have a free plan).

Comment: Run the desktop tool (or an older version of it) in a Windows virtual machine with an older version of Windows?

Comment: @Mawg That would probably work, but I'm not sure it would be worth the cost of the Windows license and the resources. Also, I don't think they still sell Windows 7, so I'd have to buy a whole new computer with that OS on it.

Comment: A quick Google for "buy cheap windows 7 license" shows them going for about US $20. Might not be ideal, but if there is no other alternative ...

Comment: @Mawg Thanks. You're right, I do see some re-sellers selling them for $40 - $99 but yes, buying a OS and running a virtual machine just to get one app working is not a viable solution for me. I appreciate the idea though. I was looking for something like what Tudor suggested or an app I found called Web Harvey.

Comment: Well, I easily found it for $20, not $40 to $99 as you say. AND, I have already bought one for $20, so I know that it is real & I didn't get ripped off. But, if you don't want to pay $20 to get that working (which is, presumably cheaper than buying a competing program), then all that I can think of if trying various versions of it  running under Wine in Linux (which you can run in a VM, if you want Windows as your main o/s).